# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in modifier invocation

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

## Issue Summary:

I encountered a `TypeError` in the code while trying to invoke a modifier in the `flashloan.sol` contract. The error message suggests an invalid type for the argument in the modifier invocation, specifically an invalid implicit conversion from contract `IPoolAddressesProvider` to contract `IPoolAddressesProvider` is being requested.

## Steps to Reproduce:

- Deploy the contract with the given code.
- Attempt to invoke the modifier in the `flashloan.sol` contract.
- Observe the `TypeError` mentioned in the error message.

## Expected Behavior:

The code should compile without any errors, and the modifier should be invoked successfully without type conversion issues.

## Actual Behavior:

Encountered a `TypeError` with the following details:

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in modifier invocation. Invalid implicit conversion from contract IPoolAddressesProvider to contract IPoolAddressesProvider requested.
  --> contracts/flashloan.sol:13:35:
   |
13 |     ) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)) {
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

## Environment:

- Solidity Compiler version: "0.8.10"
- Operating system: Windows x64

I removed the implicit type conversion from contract `IPoolAddressesProvider` to contract `IPoolAddressesProvider`

```
FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(_addressProvider)
```

also tried fixing the code with `Remix Ide` also, after spending times fixing it on local using `Hardhat` but no results unfortunately, please let me know how it can be fixed thanks!

FlashLoan.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";

abstract contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;

    constructor(
        address _addressProvider
    ) FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external returns (bool){
        // We have the borrowed funds
        // custom logic to mock arbitrage
        uint256 amountOwed = amounts + premiums;
        IERC20(assets).approve(address(POOL),amountOwed);

    return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = ""; //empty
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            receiverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns(uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner{
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 
        "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)` is not of type of `address`, it should be `_addressProvider` instead to be passed as the correct type.

This [template](https://github.com/defispartan/testnet-flash-liquidity) demonstrates the format of imports, constructor, and function calls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).